# Who put the computer in the scepter in the Avengers Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

In the Avengers Age of Ultron, the scepter contains the mind stone in addition to a computer interface to the mind stone, and an artificial intelligence program that runs on the computer.  I know that Baron von Strucker wrote the artificial intelligence program.  But who put the computer in the scepter with the mind stone?

Has the mind stone always had this computer attached to it?  Or is the computer a recent addition?

Comment: My understanding was that the "computer" that JARVIS detected *was* the Mind Stone, and the AI was the "mind" within it.  I don't think there was a computer interface artificially added to it.

Comment: Von Strucker didn't write the AI program - he and Hydra were STUDYING the AI program for their own purposes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### The Chitauri scepter is nothing more than a housing (possibly to mask the presence) for the Mind Stone. The computer described in Avengers: Age of Ultron isn't a computer in the scepter. Nor is it a computer within the Mind Stone. It is a computer-like sentience within the stone that Strucker and HYDRA scientists tried to emulate as the core of a program they were trying to create.

[image]

- In the image above, we are shown Jarvis on the left (arguably, a very sophisticated artificial intelligence, created by Tony Stark) but on the right was the neural network of the Mind Gem, far more sophisticated, appearing to be a neural network, not just a series of programming structures. It has a far more organic appearance and could almost be considered alive.
- The HYDRA scientists were not smart enough to do this on their own, the Mind Stone enhanced Strucker's intelligence which allowed them to create most of the program they were going to use for their killer robots.
- Tony Stark and Dr. Banner reverse-engineered the HYDRA scientists work and their goal was to improve upon the Jarvis programming in the hopes of generating a new intelligence capable of controlling his own Iron Legion, an intelligence with greater capacity and autonomy. This autonomous program became Ultron.

#### Comic Apocrypha

**Powers of The Mind Gem**

We are introduced to the Mind Gem during the Thanos Quest where it was in the hands of the Elder of the Universe known as The Grandmaster. The Grandmaster used the Gem to increase his intelligence making him even more formidable in his lifelong pursuit of games and other probability-driven challenges. It did not help him against the Mad Titan, however.

**The Mind Gem in the canon Marvel Universe has rarely been depicted functioning by itself. We have seen the Mind Stone from the MCU do some but not all of these features. It can:**

- Increase the intelligence of its wielder to superhuman capacities.
- Give its wielder the ability to read the minds of others and translate languages instantly. A user can read and alter the dreams of others. An experienced psychic can manipulate and erect psychic barriers in the user's mind or the minds of others.
- The wielder can perform astral projection, directing their consciousness to appear in other locations, even at great distances.
- It can give the possessor the ability to manipulate and control the minds of people under its influence.
- It has the capacity to give the wielder extreme telekinetic ability limited by their experience manipulating telekinetic powers. The more experience a wielder has, the more they are able to move, lift and control.
- In conjunction with the other Infinity Gems, it may have powers that have not been depicted.

Comment: Minor correction, Thaddeus - from the dialogue it appeared that Hydra was only STUDYING the neural network and attempting to reverse-engineer it for their own purposes, essentially the same exact thing that Tony & Bruce did. As Tony said, they were researching the program, not writing it. Or, as Tony put it, they were "knocking on a very specific door".

Comment: Are most of those powers confirmed? Loki already had his own magic (specialising in projections) and Wanda was ret-conned to already have had powers.

Answer (score 8):

You're a little confused.  It's not that there's literally a computer program in the scepter, it's that the Mind Stone contains something similar to a brain, or intelligence.  Strucker didn't put it there, it was there to begin with and both HYDRA and the Avengers utilized it to develop advanced technology.  JARVIS, Tony, and Bruce were able to adapt and integrate that into their Ultron work to make the AI we see in the film running around calling itself Ultron.

We don't know how/why that intelligence got into the Mind Stone, at the moment, we should probably assume it's always been there.  After all, it is the *Mind* Stone, so it containing a literal mind isn't a random thing.

Comment: My interpretation of this has always been that the Mind Stone is "smart" enough to expose itself to its user in a way that makes sense to them; since Stark was familiar with OS design it appeared as an OS.

Answer (score -1):

I was just hoping they were researching some of Pym's a.i. work, & were trying to use it to study the Mind Stone, which in turn corrupted it. (Remember, Stark said they "deep-sixed the data", so they got the a.i. program info from somewhere...)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question was who put the computer in the scepter; this appears to be more of a comment on the other answers than a response to the question itself.  Please don't post comments as answers; when you earn some reputation you'll be able to comment on other people's posts.  In the meantime you might want to take the [tour].